# pandas data frame, apply t-test on rows simultaneously grouping by column names (have duplicates!)

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, apply

I have a data frame with particular readouts as indexes (different types of measurements for a given sample), each column is a sample for which these readouts were taken. I also have a treatment group assigned as the column name for each sample. You can see the example below.

What I need to do: for a given readout (row) group samples by treatment (column name) and perform a t-test (Welch's t-test) on each group (each treatment). T-test must be done as a comparison with one fixed treatment (control treatment). I do not care about tracking out the sample ids (it was required, now I dropped them on purpose), I'm not going to do paired tests.

For example here, for readout1 I need to compare treatment1 vs treatment3, treatment2 vs treatment3 (it's ok if I'll also get treatment3 vs treatment3).

Example of data frame:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(27).reshape((3, 9)),
                 index=['readout1', 'readout2', 'readout3'],
                 columns=['treatment1', 'treatment1', 'treatment1',\
                          'treatment2', 'treatment2', 'treatment2', \
                          'treatment3', 'treatment3', 'treatment3'])
```

```html
frame
Out[757]: 
          treatment1  treatment1  ...  treatment3  treatment3
readout1           0           1  ...           7           8
readout2           9          10  ...          16          17
readout3          18          19  ...          25          26

[3 rows x 9 columns]
```

I'm fighting it for several days now. Tried to unstack/stack the data, transposing the data frame, then grouping by index, removing nan and applying lambda. Tried other strategies but none worked. Will appreciate any help.
thank you!

Comment: just guessing if you print `{'df'+str(e) : frame.loc[:,i] for e,i in enumerate(list(set(itertools.combinations(frame.columns,2))))}` so you get the desired combinations in a dict? `import itertools` first

Comment: thanks, I did end up just transforming the table into a dictionary.
I just hoped that there is a more elegant way to do it